# Unable to run Cassandra 4.0.7 using Java 17

Tags: cassandra

Trying to install cassandra 4.0.7 on my laptop. When i type cassandra in cmd it simply exits.
Used gitbash for running the cassandra. Here the output looks like.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBF1Q.png)error

removed UseConcMarkSweepGC from the jvm11-server.options file. But not working.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra). For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

Cassandra 4.0.7 does not support java17. This support is expected for Cassandra 5.x (late 2023 as of today). Please downgrade to Java 11 with tools like `jenv`

Check the current status here
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-16895

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I completely misread the question the first time and didn't realise that the question was about Java 17. 

Answer (score 4):

Apache Cassandra 4.x does not support Java 17.

Support for Java 11 was added in Cassandra 4.0 ([CASSANDRA-9608](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9608), [CASSANDRA-16894](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-16894)). At this point, Cassandra 4.x releases support both Java 8 and Java 11. Note that C* 3.0 + 3.11 (and older releases) only support Java 8.

Support for Java 17 LTS will be added in a future release of Cassandra ([CASSANDRA-16895](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-16895)). When that does land, support for Java 8 will be dropped paving the way for just Java 11 + Java 17. Cheers!